# ¿por que asignar el mismo nombre tanto a una variable como a una funcion?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, es6

```
const Hola = function Hola() {
   _classCallCheck(this, Hola);
};
```

Comment: Puede que así se entienda mejor el código?

Comment: cuando da un error en node en el stacktrace aparece el nombre de la funcion, que es mas descriptivo que la linea del fichero, pero igual, las razones depende del desarrollador, no afecta al programa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ese tipo de sintaxis es llamando [Function Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) o expresion de funcion.

No hay diferencia entre la declaracion de una funcion y una expresion de funcion ya que al final ambas proveen la referencia de la funcion en cuestion:

```js
// expresion de funcion
var a = function a(){
  console.log("imprimiendo a");
}

function b(){
  console.log("imprimiendo b");
}

a();
b();
```

Una de las razones por la que se utilizaría una expresion de funcion seria para identificar la función a la que la variable esta haciendo referencia. Por ejemplo imagina el siguiente caso:

```js
var expresion = function a(){
      console.log("funcion de expresion");
}


var anonima = function(){
  console.log("funcion anonima");
}


debugger;
```

Si vas a la consola de desarrollo veras como al poner el mouse sobre la variable `expresion`, puedes identificar la referencia y nombre exacto de la función que contiene que es `a`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero no pasa lo mismo con la variable anónima:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nota como la identifica con el nombre de la variable ya que es anomina. Si en un futuro se editara la referencia de la funcion a otra funcion anonima, no habría forma de saber cual es el origen de la funcion.

Entonces, respondiendo a tu pregunta del porque el mismo nombre, habría que preguntarle al desarrollado ya que no tiene sentido. La variable esta declarada como constante por lo que hubiese sido mejor declarar una función de manera estandarizada.

Comment: No soy el dueño de la pregunta. Pero excelente respuesta me ha quedado totalmente claro

Comment: Muchisimas gracias Einer de verdad aclaraste totalmente mi duda.